# What properties does navigationOptions take in react-native?

Tags: react-native, stack-navigator

There's mention of the property navigationOptions in this page here:

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/navigation.html

I can't seem to find the full list of properties that navigationOptions is supposed to take?  Where do I get this information?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here are some options:

1. title
2. header
3. headerTitle
4. headerBackTitle
5. headerTruncatedBackTitle
6. headerRight
7. headerLeft
8. headerStyle
9. headerTitleStyle
10. headerBackTitleStyle
11. headerTintColor
12. headerPressColorAndroid
13. gesturesEnabled

You can find more details all options and props in the following doc:

This link is no longer in use.

<strike>https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigators/stack#Screen-Navigation-Options</strike>

Instead of that You can use Below link for the answer.

[navigationoptions-used-by-stacknavigator](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator.html#navigationoptions-used-by-stacknavigator)

Hope it helps